# Is there a way to fetch the followers of an Instagram user by ID?

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm currently working on a project that involves fetching the followers of an Instagram user using the API. In the past, I saw there was api to achieve this using the URL format: https://graph.instagram.com/user_id/followers?fields=id,username&access_token=...

However, it seems that with the recent changes in the Instagram Graph API and Basic Display API, I couldn't find a straightforward way to accomplish this. I've checked the documentation thoroughly, but it doesn't provide clear information on fetching followers.

Could anyone guide me on the correct method or endpoint to use in order to fetch the followers of an Instagram account using the latest API versions? Your assistance would be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help.

#InstagramAPI #GraphAPI #Developers #APIHelp

I already tried with various endpoints and fileds to achive this. but none of them work and no clue in the documentation